# Getting an information about type of input ( main args )

Tags: java, casting

How can I get information about the type of input ?
String[] array in `main` only accepts strings. If someone enters a number into `args` how can I find out if it is a number written in string variable ?
Example code would be very helpful. ( Sorry if I asked really stupid question )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way is to check using `parseInt`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
{
    try
    {
        Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    }
    catch(NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println("It is not a number.");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd argue this is bad practice because it's not an exceptional circumstance,  StringUtils would be a more appropriate solution.  They shouldn't be used for flow control http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729379/why-not-use-exceptions-as-regular-flow-of-control

Answer (score 3):

`args[]` takes in all the arguments supplied to the main method, so `args[0]` although as a String, if you expected the user to enter an Integer you could cast this with...

`Integer.parseInt(args[0]);`

Consider the fact though it may through a `java.lang.NumberFormatException` so you'd have to check that in case the user entered an invalid input.  If you wanted to do something based on if this is truly a number, look at [StringUtils.isNumeric](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isNumeric%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) which is in Apache Commons Lang, why reinvent the wheel?

The reason I would go for this rather than `try{} catch()` is because exceptions should be used for exceptional circumstances.

Comment: No i mean, if user enters a String my program should use different method, than if users enter a number.

Comment: Added notes regarding StringUtils.isNumeric

Answer (score 2):

The *type* of your argument is always just `String`. If that string is "", "Foo" or "182" is at this point totally arbitrary.

These strings may, or may not be valid *representations* of a number. You need to convert the strings to your number type (e.g. `Integer.parseInt`) for `int`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code. This code will first check whether the input entered is number or not. If it is number it will parse that to num else it will give you the default value.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    char chararr[] = args[0].toCharArray();
    int num = 0 ;
    boolean isNumber = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < chararr.length;i++) {
        if (Character.isDigit(chararr[i])) {
            isNumber = true;
        }
        else {
            isNumber = false;
            break;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("str is number "+isNumber);
    if (isNumber) {
         num = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    }
    System.out.println("number is "+num);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't "know" of which type a `String` value is. What you may try is to check if a `String` can be converted into some other type. Even if it can, it does not mean, the `String` value was meant to be of that type. Here a example:

```
int value = Integer.parseInt("4711");
```

This statement would result in an `Integer` with value `4711`, which does not mean, the `String` was meant to be a codified `Integer`.